# custom sprockets preprocessor & asset precompiling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I am having an issue with using custom sprockets preprocessors when precompiling assets in rails 3.2.3

I am using the [sprockets-urlrewriter](https://github.com/carlhoerberg/sprockets-urlrewriter) along with twitter bootstrap.

In development, the preprocessor declared in an initializer is working just fine.  `Rails.application.assets.register_preprocessor 'text/css', Sprockets::UrlRewriter`

It successfully converts the relative URLs in my CSS `url(\"../img/glyphicons-halflings.png\")` to `url(bootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings.png)`

wonderful.

But when I precompile my assets: `rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets`, the compiled css has the original relative path.  How can i troubleshoot precompiling my assets with the preprocessor?

Comment: ok.  i remembered with Heroku i needed to set `initialize_on_precompile` to false.  since no initializers are called, neither are the sprockets preprocessors.  what would be the best workaround this (aside from precompiling locally and add my assets to git)?